# server side events behind varnish-cache, not sending message or messages never pushed

Tags: varnish

I have a backends that use Redis pub/sub that publish messages to subscribers. this is working very well in NGINX. but when i place a varnish in front of my NGINX, messages never pushed to browsers although they are being published by the go-servers.

my config foro varnish is default  installed out from apt-get install, using VCL config. I updated the default config to point to my NGINX

```
backend default {
    .host = "NGINX_url";
    .port = "80";
}
```

other than this, i left it commented.

Sorry if I have asked this twice, from the forums and here. I think varnish is a great and awesome software and I'm eager to implement this on our production apps.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When pushing messages from the server to the browsers i suppose you are using a websocket. To use websockets with varnish you have to setup the following you your vcl

```
sub vcl_pipe {
     if (req.http.upgrade) {
         set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
     }
}
sub vcl_recv {
     if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
         return (pipe);
     }
}
```

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/websockets.html